# With the input value, query whether the category contains the name or the company name. I want to return the company list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

With the input value, query whether the category contains the name or the company name. I want to return the company list.

In the query method in the controller, return $comp; sounds empty.

Controller:

```
public function query(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->what;
    $companies = Company::where('deleted_at', null);

    if ($search) {
        $categories = Category::where('deleted_at', null);
        $comp = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if (Str::contains(mb_strtolower($category->name), mb_strtolower($search)))
                array_push($comp, $category->company);
        }


        return $comp;
    }
}
```

Category model:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

Company model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id')->withDefault([
        'name' => '-']);
}
```

Category migration:

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('upper_id')->default(0);
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('slug', 100);
        $table->string('description', 500)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Company migration:

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('slug', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: welcome to SO. What does not work?

Comment: In the query method in the controller, return $comp; sounds empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want the company list it's better to query in Company Model.

```
$companies = Company::with('category')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
            ->orWhereHas('category', function($query) use($search) {
                $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
            })
            ->get();
```

It will return the collection of companies where search is like the name of company or name of the category.
If you want to query in Category model you need to use something like

```
$categories = Category::where('name', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                ->orWhereHas('companies', function($query) use($search) {
                    $query->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search}%");
                })
                ->get();
```

Now you can push the companies associated with each category and send the array to blade. But the best way is just send the categories to blade and iterate them like

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->companies as $company)
    {{ $company->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```